# Get values from a listview

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to get the values of a listview that has an edittext for the user to place the values, and I get them when saving the information. I got it; The problem is that I use listview.getchildat (i) and I can only get the children that are visible on the screen, but sometimes they are more than 50 children and I can not get more than the 8 visible, I would like to see if there is any way to get Values not visible. This is the code I have and I get only visible children:

```
for (i = 0; i < feedList.size(); i++) {
            View v = lv.getChildAt(i);
            System.out.println("Posicion i: " + i);
            TextView cobro = null;
            try {

                cobro = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.col_cobro);
                System.out.println("CobroValidador: " + cobro.getText().toString());
                sumaValidaCobro += Convert(cobro.getText().toString());
                tstSuma += Convert(cobro.getText().toString());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                validaCobrado++;
                System.out.println("Valida cobrado: " + validaCobrado);
          //      tstSuma += Convert(cobro.getText().toString());

            }
        }
```

I'm using a listview with 4 col, this is the adapter.

```
 SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, feedList, R.layout.view_item, new String[]{"doc", "emp", "original", "saldo", "cobro"}, new int[]{R.id.col_doc_id, R.id.col_emp, R.id.col_original, R.id.col_saldo, R.id.col_cobro});
        lv.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

I need to get the new values of the last col, it's an EditText

FeedList is the initial adapter with which the listview is loaded, but the user can enter the values manually in the listview. When I save I can not use the original, I need to get all the data that the user entered. Any way to achieve this?

Greetings.

Comment: I resolved this problem changing from ListView to RecycleView, works very nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem changing from ListView to RecycleView, works very nice

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` has a recycling mechanism, invisibel items might be recycled and lost the data they hold. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14108676/7989290) for more details.

If you wish to reserve data from those `EditTexts` in the `ListView`, you might want to implement your own adapter, and put a listener on every `EditText` when inflating items.

Also, [For a more modern, flexible, and performant approach to displaying lists, use RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView).

Comment: I added the listview adapter, I'm using 4 col at the adapter

Comment: @Heisenberg06 regardless of col number, you could still try it this way. Just replace `EditText` with your list item type(like `LinearLayout` etc.).

Comment: @Heisenberg06 you might want to check out my _**another idea**_ in my edit

Comment: What do you wanna say with register EditText?

Comment: @Heisenberg06 by `register()` I mean 'save' the handlers of `EditText`...or put it another way, send thoes instances of `EditText` to your activity, and hold them, which allow you to `getText()` from them afterwards. You can consider `register()` as one callback method in your parent activity. (sorry for my poor english :P)